# One jQuery Instance, Two Domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xss

I have two pages: **a.example.com** and **b.example.com**

**a.example.com** includes jQuery

**a.example.com** contains an iframe pointing to **b.example.com**

both pages have document.domain set to the same parent domain, **example.com**

How can I use the jQuery include from **a.example.com** to call $.ajax({ url: "**b.example.com**" }) from inside the **b.example.com** iframe?

*In other words: Both pages can currently access the Javascript of one another, but I can not get the AJAX call to function without throwing XSS errors. That is, without including jQuery on b.example.com too. How do I avoid including jQuery twice?*

Example of the contents of the iframe:

```
<script>
document.domain = "example.com";

function proxyAjax() {
   var jQueryParent = parent.$.sub();

   // Chrome gives error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://b.example.com/. Origin http://a.example.com/ is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
   jQueryParent.ajax({
      url : "http://b.example.com/",
      success : function() {
         console.debug("Success");
      }
   });
}

proxyAjax();
</script>
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the code you're trying to run?

Answer (score 1):

Setting `document.domain` will not allow you to make cross-domain AJAX calls.  If you don't really need the request to originate from b.example.com, you could do this:

In the a.example.com document, have this JavaScript function:

```
function makeAjaxRequest(callback) {
    $.ajax({ url: '...', success: callback })
}
```

Then in the b.example.com document, have a script that calls `makeAjaxRequest` in the a.example.com document with a callback function defined in b.example.com.